# My android virtual device doesnt open after launching it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager

[The android emulator is out of shape and doesn't open on clicking it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz3Jh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should cold boot it. Or, delete and recreate it. Then it should work.

Comment: 1.i did cool boot   2.Deleted and recreated  3.uninstalled and installed android studio again

Comment: create another virtual device. Like pixel 2 or nexus 5. And let me know the update.

Comment: It is still the same... It is out of shape... Even if I alt + tab to the emulator window it doesn't open